# stemming and lemmatization python nltk with swear words

Tags: python, nltk

I wanted to know if anyone had experience with **stemming** or **lemmatization** with **swear words** as when I try with **nltk** they are not considered similiar for example deviations of the **f word** do not all come down to single root as hoped or the **s word** for that matter.
If someone has a solution with **nltk** that would be great otherwise I am open to another python library.

The main purpose of the problem is flagging **inapropriate comments**.

Thank you

Comment: How are you using stemmed/lemmatized swear words to flag comments? There may be a more straightforward method such as taking the root word and seeing if it is in any of the words in the comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , I am using textblob to flag comments using sentiment analysis and I was hoping to kind of build on this with some kind of either flagging comments or verifying same types of words in comments as the sentiment analysis is not as accurate as I would like. So to improve on the sentiment analysis using stemming , lemmatization or something else.

Comment: What function in NLTK are you using to lemmatize? Depending on that, you could adapt the code to make it treat the swear words. I don't know a function out-of-the-box that does that.

Comment: I found this http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#wordlist under wordlist it is very good for what I was looking for wondering if anyone has anything to build on this would be great. It has not only the words but common abbreviations etc..